# Inner Joins in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, select, hql

I'm unable to execute this HQL command:

```
String hql = "select t.ticketName, t.idTicket, d.jour from Ticket as t inner join DateTraitement as d  on d.idTicket=t.idTicket where t.idTicket= 1";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql) ;
List<Abc> result = query.list();
```

i have this error :    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idTicket of: m.m.model.DateTraitement [select t.ticketName, t.idTicket, d.jour from m.m.model.DateTraitement as d, m.m.model.Ticket as t where d.idTicket = t.idTicket]

here is my DateTreatment class:

enter code here

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_date_traitement", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer idDateTrait;
@Column(name = "jour", length = 50)
private int jour;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_ticket")
private Ticket ticket;

public Integer getIdDateTrait() {
    return idDateTrait;
}

public void setIdDateTrait(Integer idDateTrait) {
    this.idDateTrait = idDateTrait;
}

public int getJour() {
    return jour;
}

public void setJour(int jour) {
    this.jour = jour;
}

public Ticket getTicket() {
    return ticket;
}

public void setTicket(Ticket ticket) {
    this.ticket = ticket;
}
```

}

I don't know what I'm missing. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error message or something? Please specify what "I'm unable" means.

Comment: i have this error :    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idTicket of: m.m.model.DateTraitement [select t.ticketName, t.idTicket, d.jour from m.m.model.DateTraitement as d, m.m.model.Ticket as t where d.idTicket = t.idTicket]

Comment: Now please click *edit* below your question and paste that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
UPDATED AFTER NEW QUESTION:

```
String hql = 
     "select d.ticket.ticketName, d.ticket.idTicket, d.jour 
     from DateTraitment as d
     where d.ticket.idTicket = 1";

Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql) ;

List<Abc> result = query.list();
```

Comment: pleaaase need help from here!! no idea about the problem??

Comment: @chahra: I've read the error in the other comment. That means you not have a property in DateTreatment called idTicket. Have you mapped this property in your DateTreatment object?

Comment: here is my DateTreatment class:

Comment: i paste it into my question

Comment: but there is no Inner join in ur new answer !

Comment: @chahra: Hi, explicit INNER JOIN not useful as you have created your objects. When I refer d.ticket the underlying SQL query has mapped as INNER JOIN between DateTratment and Ticket

Comment: @chahra: I'm glad to help you, I hope my answer was complete ;) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Error itself self explains the issue, Class `DateTreatment` should have property `idTicket`.

Looks like the Id you have defined is

```
@Column(name = "id_date_traitement", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer idDateTrait;
```

Either you can change this to `idTicket` or in your query use `d.idDateTrait`

Cheers !!